# What could be possible reason for runtime error in my code?

Tags: c++

Me again. Getting runtime error for my program below. I am running this code in 
**C++ 5.3.0 - GNU C++ Compiler with options: -lm -lcrypt -O2 -pipe -DONLINE_JUDGE**

my code is....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



struct myString{
    string inputString;
    string lowerString;
    string key;

    myString(string str)
    : inputString(str)
    {
        priority_queue<char> q;
        lowerString = "";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            char ch = tolower(str[i]);
            lowerString += ch;
            q.push(ch);
        }
        key = "";
        while(!q.empty()){
            key += q.top();
            q.pop();
        }
    }
};
struct CompareString {
    bool operator()(myString const& ms1, myString const& ms2)
    {
        string s1 = ms1.inputString;
        string s2 = ms2.inputString;

        bool result = true;
        int minLen = s1.length();
        if(minLen > s2.length())
            minLen = s2.length();

        for(int i=0;i<minLen;i++){
            if(isupper(s1[i]) && isupper(s2[i])){
                if(s1[i] < s2[i]){
                    return false;
                }else if(s1[i] > s2[i]){
                    return true;
                }
            }else if(isupper(s1[i])){
                return false;
            }else if(isupper(s2[i])){
                return true;
            }else if(s1[i] < s2[i]){
                return false;
            }else if(s1[i] > s2[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return s2.length() > s1.length();
    }
};


int main(){
    string str;
    priority_queue<myString, vector<myString>, CompareString> sortedInput;
    map<string,int> presenceCount;
    while((cin >> str), str != "#"){
        myString ms(str);
        sortedInput.push(ms);

        map<string, int>::iterator it = presenceCount.find(ms.key);
        if(it == presenceCount.end()){
            presenceCount.insert(make_pair(ms.key,1));
        }else {
            it->second++;
        }
    }

    while(!sortedInput.empty()){
        myString ms = sortedInput.top();
        map<string, int>::iterator it = presenceCount.find(ms.key);
        if(it->second <= 1)
            cout << ms.inputString << endl;
        sortedInput.pop();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I am learing c++. And trying solve some uva problems. Right now i am trying the problem number [156 - Ananagrams](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=0&problem=92&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2023835055)
Someone please help me to understand why i am getting runtime error here ??

Comment: Do you know where the run time error happens?  If not t sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Hi Me.  Please use a debugger and edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  There is no point in other people debugging your program for you.  Make the first attempt, then post a question (after researching the internet).

Comment: You are missing final `else` statement in your `if-then-else` ladders.

Comment: You can *transform* an `std::string` to all lower case by using `std::transform` and `std::tolower`.  Search the internet for more details.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell because you've made it complicated so I haven't checked exhaustively, but I suspect your comparator does not implement a strict-weak ordering.   If that is so, it will cause various operations on your `priority_queue` to have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Without any input running this code ends with [std::bad_alloc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lnQuRm0vK4czXLVa).

This give me a clue you are reading data incorrectly so I sppoted this line:

```
while((cin >> str), str != "#")
```

This doesn't do what you are expecting. Comma is operator is evaluated to result of expression on the right side. So when there is no reading `str` is empty `str != "#"` is always true and loop never ends.

Fix it like this:

```
while((cin >> str) && str != "#")
```

I didn't check if there are other errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem and i am totally surprised that `return 1;` could cause this problem. Thank you guys for helping me with this.